# How can i send extra data to ajax done method?

Tags: jquery

I'll make it simple, i have this code :

```
$('#album_item' + currentCell).on('blur', '#caption_input' + currentCell, function(e) {

    e.stopPropagation();

    // we extract the num in the id to use related elements
    var numberPattern = /\d+/g;
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    id = id.match(numberPattern);

    // save caption, when done reInitFlip
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insert_caption",
        data: {
            thumbnail: file.thumbnail_url,
            caption: $('#caption_input' + currentCell).val()
        }
    }).done(reInitFlip(data, id));

});​
```

reInitFlip is as following :

```
var reInitFlip = function(data,id) {

};
```

All my items are in a list with an incremating ID, so i'm trying to send the function the
ID value of the item invoked this event, as there could be a few.

How can i send that data to the method? or alterntivly how can i know which element invoked the ajax call inside reInitFlip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
}).done(function(data) {
    reInitFlip(data, id)
});
```

Comment: Havn't thought about that... seems like a workaround for me, is this the only option? i mean besides using global, etc..

Comment: Workaround? As to me this is the most natural way.

Comment: i'm new to jQuery i guess that's why :) well it did work so thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of the default context of the ajax call.

The .done function is passed (data,textStatus,jqXHR) parameters.

Also, by default, within the done function, "this" will contain the settings of the ajax call.

In the case specified in the question, you can simply use the global var id.

However, in cases where the global variable may change after the ajax call is made, you can pass the data to the .ajax options and then reference the settings using "this".

```
for (var i=0; i++; i<10)
{
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.html?id="+i,
      customvarforid: i

     }).done(function(data) {
    
     console.log(this.customvarforid + ": " + this.url + ":" + data);
    });


}  //end for
```

For more details on jquery ajax:
https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/